# Return wordpress user to original page after they register

Tags: wordpress, redirect, filter, registration

I'm working on a Wordpress site which has various features that are only available to registered users. I need to prompt the users to register/login at various places, and after they do I want to return them to the original page they were on.

I know how to do this manually, but my suspicion is that there is a way to take advantage of built-in Wordpress functions, so I'd rather not "reinvent the wheel." I've searched for solutions but I've only found strategies that involve a hard-coded, static return page after registration. I DON'T want to do this. I'm looking for a way to keep track of the referring page, and return to it after registration. Thanks in advance.

EDIT1: I've located what I thought I was looking for, which is the filter hook [login_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect). It appears to be designed for exactly what I want to do, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

The implementation should be pretty straight-forward, so I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong. Here's the code in my theme's functions.php:

```
function redirect_to_function($redirect_to, $request, $user)
{
return 'http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect_page/';

}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_to_function', 10, 3 );
```

EDIT2:
I think I solved the mystery as to why the redirect_to filter isn't working, as well as the solution using the hidden field named "redirect_to" (see comments below). I'm using the s2Member plugin to manage membership levels, and I suspect that it is overriding the built-in wordpress functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was related to a specific plugin I was using that was over-riding my hooks. See my edits above.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not such plugins which match your requirement 100%. Bit i suggest to customize this plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

Comment: I know this plugin, but it doesn't do what I want. It provides the option to set static redirection pages (after any login). I need to track the original page so that I'm not redirecting ALL users to the same random page.

Comment: you can just make your login forms include a hidden POST variable "redirect_to" with the address of the page people are on.

Comment: I'm not quite following how this connects to the Peters-login-redirect plugin. Can you unpack what you mean?

Comment: if you add hidden field in login form with name "redirect_to" and set it's value URL of page before login then WP automatically redirect user on that page after login.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know about this. I'll give it a try. Is there an elegant way to pass the url of whatever the previous page was (so it's not always the same redirect)? I'm sure I could send it as a url parameter and $_GET it, but this seems a bit clunky.